Using WiFiServer in blocking mode
I am learning ESP32 network programming and I started by writing a simple telnet server. It uses a WiFiServer object to listen on port 23 and just log anything it receives to the serial monitor.
Sample code seems to be along the lines of:
  // Listen on port 23
  WiFiServer server(23);
  server.begin();

  // Loop to handle connections
  while (true) {
    // Wait for a connection
    WiFiClient client = server.available();
    if (client) {
      ...

This works fine, but the call to server.available() is non-blocking so the loop is running continuously and using 100% CPU. On a PC I would use a socket in blocking mode so that calling accept() would suspend the thread until data was available. I do this because it's pretty antisocial to consume 100% CPU on a multitasking OS.
My question is whether there is a way to make Server.available() behave like the sockets accept() function and block until a connection is available. If not, what is considered best practice? Just let the CPU run at 100%, or is there some better way to code this more efficiently? Maybe just use the same BSD sockets API that I would on Linux?

just let the arduino thread run as the RTOS schedules it

@Juraj I am creating tasks (using vTaskCreate()) to hand off the client to, like the accept then fork approach in Linux. If I let the main thread spin won't that starve the other tasks of CPU?

add a small delay if you want. the WiFiServer and WiFiClient are implemented over Berkley/POSIX sockets API of the IDF/LwIP. maybe you want to use it directly

@Juraj Thanks :-)

It seems there is no way to make the WiFiServer available() function block until it receives a connection. If CPU usage is an issue the solution appears to be a short delay after calling the function, as Juraj suggested in a comment.
If anyone is interested the sockets API works fine. I put together the code below as a quick test and it works as expected. If you telnet to the ESP32 it prints a message then closes the connection:
#include <lwip/sockets.h>
#include "WiFi.h"

void ConnectWiFi() {
  WiFi.begin("my_ssid", "my_password", 6);
  int loopcnt = 0;
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.printf("Connecting: time %d, WiFi status = %d, signal = %d\n", loopcnt++, WiFi.status(), WiFi.RSSI());
    delay(1000);
  }
  Serial.printf("Connected: %s\n", WiFi.localIP().toString().c_str());
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  ConnectWiFi();
}

void loop() {
  // Create, bind and listen on port 23
  int sock_srv = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
  
  struct sockaddr addr_in;
  memset(&addr_in, 0, sizeof(addr_in));
  struct sockaddr_in* p_addr_in = (struct sockaddr_in*) &addr_in;
  p_addr_in->sin_family = PF_INET;
  p_addr_in->sin_port = htons(23);
  p_addr_in->sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  bind(sock_srv, &addr_in, sizeof(addr_in));

  listen(sock_srv, 1);
 
  // Loop to handle connections
  while (true) {
    // Wait for a connection
    sockaddr addr_client;
    memset(&addr_client, 0, sizeof(addr_client));
    int sock_client = accept(sock_srv, &addr_client, NULL);
    Serial.println("Accepted connection");

    // Just end a message then close the socket
    String s = "Welcome and goodbye!\r\n";
    send(sock_client, s.c_str(), s.length(), 0);
    closesocket(sock_client);
  }   
}


Hi, and welcome to Arduino:SE.  I'm not sure if this was intended to be an answer to your question or supplementary information (which should probably be edited into your question, rather than posted as an answer).

@sempaiscuba good point, it's an alternative approach not an answer to whether WiFiServer can be made to work in blocking mode. I'll delete it until I have an answer to that.
